# Why is xCode reserving so much disk space when running?

Tags: xcode, disk, diskspace

I've noticed then when I have 1 or more projects open in xCode, free disk space on my disk quickly goes down to few (~40) MBs. I want to understand ***why* is this happening**, even when developing a relatively small iOS project and **what can I do to release disk space right after closing xCode** without rebooting the system (right now it takes some time for the system to free the disk space).

I'm running xCode 4.4.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: And how much free space do you expect to have normally? Can you run a disk profiling utility (like [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/)) to find out where all the space is disappearing to?

Comment: Thanks, I've checked my disk. I know I should have more free space. What I curious about though is why/what for does xCode or iOS simulator need so much disk space for.

Comment: Well, part of the reason I asked about how much free space you expect is to try to figure that out - if Xcode is taking up a few GB, that might be a result of caching or indexing gone awry, but if it's an order of magnitude or so higher (maybe closer to 100GB), that's a much different - and potentially more serious - problem.

Comment: Same problem here. Looks like Xcode "leaks" disk space 0.5GB at a time. Every build it leaks hundreds of megabytes. There is no need for this - restarting causes no problems but frees all disk space. Performance IMPROVES by restarting, so its not a cache (or, if it is, its a very badly written one)

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I end up loosing 10-12Gb after a few hours of work and am forced to reboot to regain the space

Comment: Why are you using an out-of-date version of the app? Have you tried with the latest version (4.6.3, I think)? This could be a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @user1118321, I've asked the question in Sep 2012. I haven't been using xCode a lot lately but the problem hasn't been fixed in newer version of xCode.

Answer (score 0):

Why is is using disk space?:  It's either creating tmp files or backing stores for the VM of runaway sub-processes a backing store is a tmp file.  You claim it's "so much", but without knowing how much free disk space do you have before Xcode runs, we can't tell you if it's an unusual amount.

How to reclaim without rebooting: If it's tmp files, you may get lucky with the script at http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040919005905173.  If you're not lucky, you'll have to figure out where the tmp files are, then delete them.  If it's processes, you can figure out which by comparing the output of 'ps aux' before/after Xcode, followed by 'kill -9 '.